# Use a pipe which depends on a service in another service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services, angular-pipe

In a service A, I need to use a pipe P. This pipe P needs a service B to work.  What I did so far in something like this:

My P pipe definition

```
export class PPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private aService: AService) {}

  transform(value:number) : string {
    return number.toString();
  }
}
```

How I use it in my service B

```
@Injectable()
export class BService {

  pPipe = new PPipe();

  myFn() {
    const nbToStr = pPipe.transform(69);
  }
}
```

But I get an error when building: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`.

Do I need to pass an instance of PPipe everytime I want to use it ? If so, how it is doable from a HTML template ?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the pipe. 
If you create something with `new` yourself, Angulars DI has no way to interact.

```
export class BService {
  constructor(private pPipe:PPipe) {}
```

This way Angular creates a `PPipe` instance and passes dependencies to its constructor.

Comment: Building succeeds but then I get in the JS console `No provider for PPipe!`, do I need to add sthg to my `BService` ?

Comment: Ensure your pipe has a `@Pipe({ name: ....})` decorator and that it is listed in the modules `declarations: [...]`

Comment: I added it in the `providers` array of the module, and it worked ;)

Comment: Glad to hear . .

Answer (score 0):

As another answer explains, it can be solved by exposing a pipe as a provider (it's not a provider by default) and injecting it as any other service. This way `AService` will be injected into `PPipe` by Angular injector.

The only proper case for using pipe `transform` manually is when a pipe is third-party and contains useful code that is available only in pipe class (e.g. Angular built-in pipes).

If a pipe is first-party, the proper way to handle this is to not call pipe `transform` but to use `AService` in `BService` directly. The pipe has to be refactored to be as slim as possible, while `AService` contains all code that is needed to reuse pipe's functionality.